# Context menu shortcut key change Linux mint 17 Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, cinnamon

Mint 17 Cinnamon assign the context menu functionality (aka right mouse click) to a key. The default key shortcut is Shift + F10, but I would like to change that to ANY key (namely to Print button). I tried dconf editor also gconf editor but I can't find it. At the "Keyboard" in "System Settings" there is no way to change this. What i would like is equivalent to  Mint KDE under Regional & Accessibility Keyboard Shortcuts entry for Popup Menu Context.

Comment: There is some answer here: https://petermolnar.eu/linux-tech-coding/how-to-make-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-usable/ but it's for 12.10. In LM17 cinnamon there is no ~/.config/gtk-3.0 file. It is a folder, instead

Answer (score 2):

To allow you to change the Menu key to whatever you want, you have to change one setting under All Settings -> Keyboard layouts and your particular keyboard layout (mine's English (US)). After you highlight it, and click on 'Options', go to 'Switch to another layout', and check 'Menu'.

After I did this, I can then use the 'Menu' key as a keybinding for my particular Custom Shortcut in All Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I think you got it the other way round. He wants the right click functionality on Menu button, not 'how to put another functionality on Menu button'.
Do you know how to remove the binding of Shift + F10 to Context Menu?

Comment: Exactly. I havew the same wish. Any chance to do so ?

Comment: And i answer yo myself - making user hotkey after installing xdotool, with command "xdotool key Menu" do the trick

Comment: thanks @emoxam. I was able to assign shift+F10 to menukey using custom shortcuts ->  
 new command/url